# How to convert lists of class objects to a list of their attributes

Tags: python, class, inheritance

guys! So I recently started learning about python classes and objects. 
For instance, I have a following list of strings:

```
alist = ["Four", "Three", "Five", "One", "Two"]
```

Which is comparable to a class of Numbers I have:

```
class Numbers(object):
   One=1
   Two=2
   Three=3
   Four=4
   Five=5
```

How could I convert `alist` into

```
alist = [4, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```

based on the class above?

My initial thought was to create a new (empty) list and use a `for loop` that adds the corresponding object value (e.g. `Numbers.One`) to the empty list as it goes through `alist`. But I'm unsure whether that'd be the most efficient solution.

Therefore, I was wondering if there was a simpler way of completing this task using Python Classes / Inheritance.

I hope someone can help me and explain to me what way would work better and why!

Thank you!!

Comment: it's enough to use a dictionary for such simple case

Comment: A class is not the appropriate way to solve this problem. You want a dictionary instead, `map = {"One": 1, "Two": 2, ... }`.

Comment: You *can* do `[Numbers().__getattribute__(a) for a in alist]` but I don't think that's the best way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I totally agree that using a `dict` for `Numbers` would be easier and straight forward, but showing you the `Enum` way as your class involves magic numbers and sort of a valid use case for using enums.

A similar implementation using `Enum` would be:

```
from enum import Enum

class Numbers(Enum): 
    One = 1 
    Two = 2 
    Three = 3 
    Four = 4 
    Five = 5
```

Then you can use `getattr` and `Numbers.<attr>.value` to get the constant numbers:

```
In [592]: alist = ["Four", "Three", "Five", "One", "Two"]                                                                                                                                                   

In [593]: [getattr(Numbers, n).value for n in alist]                                                                                                                                                        
Out[593]: [4, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```

---

**Edit based on comment:**

If you want to get the names back from a number list:

```
In [952]: l = [4, 3, 5, 1, 2]                                                                                                                                                                               

In [953]: [Numbers(num).name for num in l]                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[953]: ['Four', 'Three', 'Five', 'One', 'Two']
```

Comment: I was wondering if I could use `Enum` to convert `[4, 3, 5, 1, 2]` back into its original state again - `["Four", "Three", "Five", "One", "Two"]`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are set on using the class, one way would be to use [`__getattribute__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

```
print([Numbers().__getattribute__(a) for a in alist])
#[4, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```

But a much better (and more pythonic IMO) way would be to use a `dict`:

```
NumbersDict = dict(
    One=1,
    Two=2,
    Three=3,
    Four=4,
    Five=5
)
print([NumbersDict[a] for a in alist])
#[4, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```

Comment: @Rikk A bit of a hack, but you can also create `NumbersDict` from the `Numbers` class using the `__dict__` attribute: `NumbersDict = {k: v for k, v in Numbers.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")}`

Comment: Would there be a way to then convert [4, 3, 5, 1, 2] back into its original state again? As ["Four", "Three", "Five", "One", "Two"].

Comment: As long as the key-value pairs are unique, you can reverse the dictionary: `NumbersDict_reversed = {v: k for k, v in NumbersDict.items()}` and then use the reversed `dict` to do the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Most objects (and hence classes) in python have the `__dict__` field, which is a mapping from attribute names to their values. You can access this field using the built-in [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars), so

```
values = [vars(Numbers)[a] for a in alist]
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: Did not previously know about `vars`

Comment: @pault: yeah, there are some interesting "hidden" builtins. Good stuff: https://treyhunner.com/2019/05/python-builtins-worth-learning/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I suppose that the words and numbers are just a trivial example, a dictionary is the right way to do it if that's not the case as written in the comments.

Your assumptions are correct - either create an empty list and populate it using for loop, or use list comprehension with a for loop to create a new list with the required elements.

## Empty list with for loop

```py
#... Numbers class defined above
alist = ["Four", "Three", "Five", "One", "Two"]
nlist = []
numbers = Numbers()
for anumber in alist:
    nlist.append(getattr(numbers, anumber))

print(nlist)
[4, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```

## List comprehension with for loop

```py
#... Numbers class defined above
alist = ["Four", "Three", "Five", "One", "Two"]
numbers = Numbers()

nlist = [getattr(numbers, anumber) for anumber in alist]

print(nlist)
[4, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```