# How to display the values of attributes of an object using a function

Tags: python

I'm creating a class in Python, and the class object has various attributes. How do I display the value of the various attributes of that object?

I found that using dir() will return a list of the attributes of the object, but I want to say something like

```py
for attr in dir(object):
   print(f'{attr}: {self.attr}')
```

Of course this is going to result in an error because self doesn't have an actual attribute called attr.

Right now, my function looks like:

```py
def display_attrs(self):
    for attr in dir(self):
        print(f'{attr}: {self.attr}')
```

The output might look like

> > len: 100
> >     
> > width: 50 
> >     height: 200

And so on. I'm using this mostly for debugging. If the program crashes I feel like it would be helpful to see the state of the object.

Comment: Take a look at the solutions here: [How to convert lists of class objects to a list of their attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794886/how-to-convert-lists-of-class-objects-to-a-list-of-their-attributes). It should give you a good idea of how to proceed.

Comment: @Andrew Allen proposed the best solution, but You ca always call the `getattr(self, attr)`

Comment: I confused myself and deleted the correct comment...look into `__dict__`

Comment: @AndrewAllen that does exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Andrew Allen in the comments, use the __dict__ dunder function on the object and it will return a dictionary representation of the object, where the key is the attribute name and the value is the attribute's value.